# Implementing sellToken in Solidity

Tags: token, solidity, remix

I am writing a token smart contract in Remix, but the sellToken always doesn't work and get the error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN9ZN.png)

Here is my code:

```
function sellToken(uint256 amount) public returns (bool){
    require(amount > 0, "You should sell some tokens");
    require(balance[msg.sender] >= amount, "You should have enough amount of tokens to sell");
    balance[msg.sender] -= amount;
    uint256 refund = amount * tokenPrice;
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(refund);
    emit Sell(msg.sender, amount);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: 1) Is the `balance` of `msg.sender` larger or equal to `amount`? ... 2) Does the contract have at least `refund` of ETH?

Comment: I resolved the problem, thanks.

Comment: Great. :) Please consider posing an answer to this question with steps how you resolved it, so that others with the same issue are able to resolve it easier.